# Rewriting subdirectory to query string parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two requirements;

- That, for example, `/product/12345` is internally redirected to `/product/product.php?product=12345`.
- That if the user tries to access `/product/product.php` in the URL bar, it is redirected to `/product/` for tidiness.

Separate, they both work correctly, but together it results in an infinite loop - I know that I'm redirecting from `/product/` to `/product.php` and back again, but the difference is internal vs external and I'm not sure how to distinguish between them.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^product/product.php /product/ [NC,R=307,END]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/product/product.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^product/(.*) /product/product.php?product=$1 [NC]
```

Answer (score 1):

There probably exist other solutions, but it works if you change two things:

1. Add a condition to the first `RewriteRule` that checks if the query string is empty, i.e. `product/product.php` without query string redirects to `/product/`.
2. Change `(.*)` in the second `RewriteRule` to `(.+)` or `([0-9]+)` to only rewrite requests containing a product id (requests to `/product/` are not rewritten).

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}        ="" [NC]
RewriteRule ^product/product\.php$ /product/ [NC,R=307,END]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/product/product\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^product/(.+)   /product/product.php?product=$1 [NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

> access `/product/product.php` in the URL bar, it is redirected to `/product/` for tidiness

You might as well also redirect `/product/product.php?product=12345` to the corresponding canonical URL (ie. `/product/12345`) - which you can do all in the *same* rule. If the product *ID* is numeric only then you should restrict your regex accordingly - this will also avoid the need for an additional condition.

For example:

```
# Canonical redirect
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?:product=(\d*))?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^product/product\.php$ /product/%1 [NC,R=307,L]

# Rewrite requests from "pretty" URL to underlying filesystem path
RewriteRule ^product/(\d*) /product/product.php?product=$1 [L]
```

The condition that checks against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable is necessary to prevent a redirect loop in this instance since the query string is entirely optional.

By restricting the match to digits-only, we avoid the need for an additional condition on the internal rewrite, `product.php` won't match. If the product *id* can contain letters then restrict the pattern to avoid dots (`.`), eg. `([^./]*)`.

Only include a `NC` flag on the internal rewrite if this is strictly necessary, otherwise this potentially creates a duplicate content issue.